# how to define (independent) the scale of x-axis and y-axis?

Tags: scaling

I want to compare 2 plots, and view that 4 lines are exactly the same tangent.

So I would like to view 2 images with the same scale in the y-axis and the same scale in the x-axis

How can I do this. AspectRatio it´s not a solution for me becasue is a ratio for the image not for the scale

```
Expr1 = -alfa + 1;
Expr2 = -2 alfa + 2;
Expr3 = 5 alfa;
Expr4 = -alfa + 1;

Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3, Expr4}, {alfa, 0, 1},
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

If you plot this one, the same lines moved up/down, you can see that the sacale of y-axis is diferent because the y-range is longer.

```
Expr1 = -alfa - 2;
Expr2 = -2 alfa + 4;
Expr3 = 5 alfa;
Expr4 = -alfa - 1;

Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3, Expr4}, {alfa, 0, 1},
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I want to maintain the same scale in the y-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Expr1 = -alfa + 1;
Expr2 = -2 alfa + 2;
Expr3 = 5 alfa;
Expr4 = -alfa + 1;

p1 = Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3, Expr4}, {alfa, 0, 1},
  BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4],
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}},
  AspectRatio -> 1];


Expr1 = -alfa - 2;
Expr2 = -2 alfa + 4;
Expr3 = 5 alfa;
Expr4 = -alfa - 1;

p2 = Plot[{Expr1, Expr2, Expr3, Expr4}, {alfa, 0, 1},
  BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4],
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend["Expressions", BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4]],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}},
  AspectRatio -> 1];

Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: perfect That´s what I wanted, but... do you know any way to obtain as independent plots?, without a grid. Because I want to save the legends with the rigth bracket option SAVE AS...

Comment: @mika Ike@ Just remove the semicolons behind the definitions of `p1` and `p2`. Now `p1` and `p2` pop up and you can save them indepently.

Comment: Yes :-) sorry!!